# PluginManager undefined in cordova js

Tags: xcode4, cordova

I created a Cordova project in Xcode 4. I add my plugin in the Cordova.plist, but in the cordova.js I get the following error:
in func:Cordova.exec

in the line:

> var v = cordova.PluginManager.exec(success, fail, service, action, args);

the cordova.PluginManager is undefined.

Do you know why?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Cordova, but based on what I have seen, you may need to make sure Cordova has loaded. To call the plugin after Cordova has finished loading, do the following in your javascript file:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  // As an example, you now have the device name, Cordova version, etc. available
  alert('Device Name: ' + device.name);
  alert('Device Cordova: ' + device.cordova);
  alert('Device Platform: ' + device.platform);
  alert('Device UUID: ' + device.uuid);
  alert('Device Version: ' + device.version);

  // Now call plugin, etc.
  var v = cordova.PluginManager.exec(success, fail, service, action, args);
}
```

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device for more information.

The [Cordova documentation for iOS plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS) provides additional detail.